# How to combine 'foreach' and value in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to view data from database in my website using CodeIgniter 3. There are 2 types of ways to view my data in this website. First is without looping, I used this code :

```
<?php $s=$sched_stud->row();?>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Full Name</th>
                        <td><?php echo $s->name;?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Level Enrolled</th>
                        <td><?php echo $s->level;?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and the second one is using foreach, this is my code :

```
<tbody>
                        <?php
                        $a=1;
                        foreach ($sched_stud as $key) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"><?php echo $a; $a++; ?>.</th>
                            <td>Tue, 8 Jan 2019</td>
                            <td>17.00 - 18.30</td>
                            <td><?php echo $key->room;?></td>
                            <td>Mrs. Adinda</td>
                            <td>Upcoming</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
```

but there are errors saying :

```
Undefined property: mysqli::$room
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: to loop you need `result()` instead of `row()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first way you are getting only one record with `row()`

SO in your second way for loop you need `result()` to get multiple records

```
                  <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $a=1;
                        foreach ($sched_stud->result() as $key) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"><?php echo $a; $a++; ?>.</th>
                            <td>Tue, 8 Jan 2019</td>
                            <td>17.00 - 18.30</td>
                            <td><?php echo $key->room;?></td>
                            <td>Mrs. Adinda</td>
                            <td>Upcoming</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
```